# Order of elements in $D_4 \times S_3$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

This problem will deal with the group $G = D_4 \times S_3$.

How many elements of each order do the groups have $D_4$ and $S_3$ have?  Using this info, determine how
many elements of each order $G$ has.  (Of course, it would be extremely tedious to compute all 48
orders one by one. You should NOT be doing that. Perhaps organize your work in a table.)

I can't figure out a good way to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: To find the subgroups of G which are isomorphic to $Z_2 \times Z_2$, do I have to find all the elements with an order of 4, which are non-abelian?

Comment: So basically you need to work out, if $x$ has order $r$, and $y$ has order $s$, what's the order of $(x,y)$? Have you thought about this? run a few experiments, maybe?

Comment: the order of (x,y) is just r*s, isn't it? 

So do I just find the order of each element of D4, and each element of S3, then do the LCM of them? I don't know the mechanics of why this would work, but it seems as it would

Comment: No (to the order being the product of the orders). What if both $x$ and $y$ have order 2? RUN SOME EXPERIMENTS.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $x \in G, y \in H$, then in $G \times H$, the $ord((x,y))=lcm(ord(x),ord(y))$

Answer (score 0):

Elements of order $2$ will come from produc of an element of order $\leq 2$ in $D_4$ and an element of order $\leq 2$ in $S_3$ (not both taken identity). Count them.

Elements of order $4$ will be product of elements of order $4$ inside $D_4$, with elements of order $\leq 2$ in $S_3$ (count them).

Elements of order $3$ lie in Sylow-3 subgroup, which is unique here, inside $S_3$, count them.

Elements of order $6$ will come from product of an element of order $3$ and commuting element of order $2$. The elements of order $2$ commuting with element of order $3$ lie in $D_4$, count how many you get.

Sylow-2 subgroup has exponent 4, so no element of order 8.

Elements of order 12 will come from element of order $3$ and commuting element of order $4$. Elements of order $3$ are in $S_3$ and with them commuting elements of order $4$ are in $D_4$, count how many you get.

The maximum order of any element in $D_4\times S_3$ is product of maximum order of element of $D_4$ (which is 4) and of $S_3$ (which is 3). So we covered all elements (except identity :P)

Comment: thanks, i'm digesting it slowly, it's making good sense i think